# Keep Intesity when converting pcl PointCloud<PointXYZI> to ros PointCloud2

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

When converting Ros PointCloud2 to pcl PointCloud you need to rename a field in the PC2 data to make it work, as can be seen [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/173396/losing-intensity-data-when-converting-between-sensor_msgspointcloud2-and-pclpointcloudt/).

My Question is, when converting from pcl PointCloud to ros PointCloud2, what is the equivalent Process. Simply Converting does not work when simply using pcl::toROSMsg() and I could not find any resources on this.
Help would be much appreciated

Comment: "Simply Converting does not work" What exactly does not work? The ROS PointCloud2 will have a field with name "intensity". You could rename the field of course, if another node expects a different name for example

Comment: @IBitMyBytes Yes renaming the field makes sense, but which field do I have to rename? I have not found this documented anywhere?